# Why won't my WebView display the URL I've specified?

Tags: cocoa, webkit

I'm working with a WebView. If I place this call in my `-awakeFromNib`:

```
[myWebView setMainFrameURL:@"http://www.google.com"];
```

I get the behavior I want. Google's homepage displays in my WebView. But, I need to set the main frame's URL in another method from a mutable array containing NSStrings.

This method call

```
[myWebView setMainFrameURL:[mutableArrayContainingNSStrings objectAtIndex:0]];
```

does not update the WebView. Do I need to tell the WebView to reload? I tried `-setNeedsDisplay:YES` and `-reload` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The WebView is an IBOutlet. I was doing the method call that was giving me problems before -awakeFromNib. Moved that one line to -awakeFromNib and it's sorted now. Thanks for the input. +1 to my list of newbie posts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a breakpoint on your action method to check that both `myWebView` and `[mutableArrayContainingNSStrings objectAtIndex:0]` are pointing to the correct objects?

Answer (score 0):

Several things

(1) I second Marc's comment in making sure that it is pointing at the correct objects

(2) It's been a while since I've dealt with WebKit directly but I know that it's possible you may have strings like "www.google.com" and strings like that won't work, you need "http://www.google.com" which you have in your first call to myWebView. Make sure all of your URL Strings are like this. It's the browser (Safari/Chrome/etc) that expands www.google.com out into http://www.google.com so that you can actually visit the site

If none of that works show the strings here so I can verify and run tests to see what's going on with the WebView